# Set default Folder View to Tiled (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

in Windows 7 how do i set the default folder view (or whatever its called) to tiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Folder Options". The screenshot is Windows XP, but it should be the same in Windows 7. In an Explorer Window navigate to "Tools", "Folder Options".

[image]

Set your preferred view and then "Apply to All Folders".

Comment: In Win 7 you get to this via 'Organise > Folder and Search Options'.
It will only set that folder view for "folders of this type" i.e. for Document, Music, Images etc. folder types.

Comment: I just checked, it's the same for Windows 7.

Comment: where is the option to set view to tiled?

Comment: Right click on some white space in the Explorer window, and then do "View, Tiled". Then click "Tools, Folder Options, View, Apply to All Folders".